# Java Code is not running due to version incompatibility of Java

Tags: java, applet

We have a web application deployed in apache tomcat application server in production with java 1.6. When user access this application from their machine which has java 1.8, the applet contents are not loading and throwing an exception in a dialog box:

> Your security setting have blocked an untrusted application from running.

We are able to get rid of this exception by adding the application URL in the browser's exception list. Since this is not possible to do on every user machine, we are looking for a permanent fix for this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An applet is -  for the web application - just static content. For java 8 clients a certificate from an instance is needed. Alternatively a JavaScript solution, drawing on canvas or such.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 all applets need to be signed in order to run. You won't get around paying for an actual certificate if you want to continue to support Java 8.

You can find a small tutorial here: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2014/01/16/still-using-applets-sign-them-or-else